# What can I do for sore nipples?

Tags: running, sports

I've continued to jog after child birth - I use a sport bra. But after jogging for a while my nipples become very sore. Is there any way I can reduce the friction between my nipples and my bra?
[Perhaps I should let the male members of this forum know that a woman's nipples are one of the most sensitive parts of her body. General chafing advice (that you would use for your elbows for instance) is really not applicable here.]

Comment: When mine are sensitive, I use round pasties. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JW25FQQ/  They have adhesive that ends up on the outer aerola and provides a layer between the nips and the jersey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NipGuards](http://www.runguards.com/products/nipguards) are a totally different way to prevent chafing, better in my opinion than Band-Aids or gels. They're shaped like an octagon, with a hollow circle in the middle, which

> allows the tip of the nipple to remain protected without having an irritating adhesive plastered on the most sensitive part of the nipple. NipGuards® use a safe, medical adhesive that is applied directly to the base of the nipple and not the chest – so sweat does not affect the adhesive – and chest hair just needs to be pushed away.

They're waterproof so you can wear them in the rain, and are comfortable under any kind of clothes. According to the website, they were designed and patented by marathon runners, used by triathletes, and are

> 100% guaranteed to work in the most grueling tests of human endurance and in the most extreme weather conditions.

Neither my husband or I run for more than a few miles at a time, so I can't vouch for that, but there may be some readers here who can. As a woman, I know exactly what you mean about sensitivity, and although these are excellent for both men and women, I believe they definitely meet the criteria you need.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of runners (male and female) wear bandaids over their nipples to minimize [chafe](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/23643/7091).

Comment: That feels painful - is there anything I can wear - like some kind of silicone pads inside my bra?

Comment: @TVMohini you can use children's bandaids. They don't have much adhesive.

Answer (score 1):

I would experiment with sports lubricants like Body Glide or Sports Slick. There are special nipple bandaids that are also used, as Eric Kaufman suggested.