# Do wee need to wear underwear while doing skipping exercise?

Tags: exercise-equipment

Do we need to wear underwear while doing skipping exercise and running?

Comment: Is your underwear hindering your movement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it harmful not to wear an underwear while running?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23608/is-it-harmful-not-to-wear-an-underwear-while-running)